# Qual a melhor forma tabela de criar as tabelas com usuários que podem ter vários emails?

Tags: mysql

Qual a melhor formar de criar a tabela email, pois o cliente pode ter varios email,

criei duas situações uma email_cliente e a outra email?

qual a melhor maneira levando em conta processamento, agilidade de consulta,

Poderiam me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada na imagem, tem 3 tabelas de email O.o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao meu ver o melhor pra "organizar" é usar `1:m`, algo como:

> [image: tables]

SQLs:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientes` (
  `idclientes` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idclientes`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emails` (
  `idemails` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `clientes_idclientes` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idemails`),
  INDEX `fk_emails_clientes_idx` (`clientes_idclientes` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_emails_clientes`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientes_idclientes`)
    REFERENCES `clientes` (`idclientes`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Exemplo de dados:

```
INSERT INTO `clientes` (`nome`) VALUES
('João'),
('Maria'),
('Raul');

INSERT INTO `emails` (`idemails`, `email`, `clientes_idclientes`) VALUES
('teste@teste.com.br', 1),
('teste1@teste.com.br', 1),
('teste2@teste.com.br', 1),
('maria1@teste.com.br', 2),
('maria2@teste.com.br', 2);
```

Se quer exibir todos clientes, até os que estão sem emails use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  `clientes`.nome AS CLIENTE_NOME,
  `emails`.email AS CLIENTE_EMAIL
FROM
  `clientes` LEFT JOIN `emails` ON `emails`.clientes_idclientes = `clientes`.idclientes
WHERE 1;
```

Resultado:

```
CLIENTE_NOME | CLIENTE_EMAIL
==================================
João         | teste@teste.com.br
João         | teste1@teste.com.br
João         | teste2@teste.com.br
Maria        | maria1@teste.com.br
Maria        | maria2@teste.com.br
Raul         | NULL
```

Se quiser exibir apenas os clientes que tem emails use o `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  `clientes`.nome AS CLIENTE_NOME,
  `emails`.email AS CLIENTE_EMAIL
FROM
  `clientes` INNER JOIN `emails` ON `emails`.clientes_idclientes = `clientes`.idclientes
WHERE 1;
```

Resultado:

```
CLIENTE_NOME | CLIENTE_EMAIL
==================================
João         | teste@teste.com.br
João         | teste1@teste.com.br
João         | teste2@teste.com.br
Maria        | maria1@teste.com.br
Maria        | maria2@teste.com.br
```

> Note que usei `LEFT JOIN` pois apenas a tabela clientes não tem "restrições", uma linha na tabela `email` deve obrigatoriamente ter um cliente na tabela `clientes`, caso você queira criar emails "soltos" terá que usar `FULL OUTER JOIN`
>
> Pra entender mais sobre isto gostaria que olhasse esta ótima resposta sobre o assunto:
>
> [**Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6448/3635)

Comment: perfeito,  explicou de maneira simples e objetiva.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor forma é você criar sua tabela de clientes com seus campos,depois criar a tabela emails com seus campos e uma chave  secundária do cliente.

Você só precisa editar sua tabela email _ cliente ao invés de definir os dois campos como chaves primárias defina apenas email _ id e defina a outra como chave secundária e adicione seu outro campo email.